# how to filter list using linq windows phone ListPicker

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have List< Parameter > = App.ViewModel.Items where Parameter has a string Category.  In the List, there are 30 Parameters with 4 distinct Category (Head, Neck, Ears and Throat).  The list populates the MainLongListSelector on the main page.

I have a _categorySelector (ListPicker) populated using :

```
 _categorySelector.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Items.Select(m => m.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```

On the SelectionChanged event handler, I want to filter to MainLongListSelector with the selected value of the ListPicker.

I have this so far, that doesn't work:

```
    private void _categorySelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        var query = (from jj in App.ViewModel.Items
                     where (_categorySelector.SelectedItem as Parameter).Category == jj.Category
                     select jj).ToList(); //doesn't work
        var qq = App.ViewModel.Items.Select(mm => mm.Category).Distinct(); //doesn't connect selected item content to query
        MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making the collection of the right type first then use the Where clause:

```
var cat = (_categorySelector.SelectedItem as Parameter).Category;
var query = App.ViewModel.Items.OfType<Parameter>().Where(jj => jj.Category == cat).ToList();
```